# How can I make this text selectable?

Tags: html, css

I created a website using a platform known as [webflow](http://webflow.com). I did so because I could get a decent website much quicker this way than I would by learning to code one. I would like to know if it is possible to make the body text in the three dropdown links found [here](http://shermanmobile.com/legal) selectable. Currently when I try to select any text in the dropdown it closes. I would still like it if users can somehow close the dropdown after opening it, but text selection is a priority. I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: the problem is that the whole dropdown is inside the <a> tag. in order to do that you need to change the structure.

Comment: Is there a way I can go about doing this while maintaining its function (showing/hiding the body text)?

Comment: yes there is thousands of ways to do that. i dont know how much you can do on webflow. if you have bootstrap use [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using interactions to expand the sub content it seems that you tried to put everything in one single link block.

For it to work you should separate the content and the trigger and place them inside a wrapper. This way the interaction needs to target the size of the content and not the dropdown link trigger.

I hope it makes sens, don't hesitate to contact me if you need help in the Webflow community.

[image]
[image]